# How can I Change Id in Grid View To Value?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

How can I Change Id in Grid View To Value?
This code below only runs for the first record how can I run it for all records?

**My Action Code :**

```cs
public JsonResult GetProductNameById(int ProductId)
{
    var productname = producteRepository.GetAll().Where(c => c.Id == ProductId).FirstOrDefault();
    return Json(productname.Name);
}
```

**Grid:**

[image]

**My view code**:

```html
@model List<ItcNetworkMarketing.Domain.Core.orderLine>

@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Count</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Products</th>
            <th>Detail</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr id="Mytr">
                <td>@item.Count</td>
                <td>@item.Price</td>             
                <td id="ProductId" name="ProductId"  >@item.ProductId</td>
                <td><a asp-controller="OderLine" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Detail</a></td>

            </tr>
        }

    </table>
}
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script>
   
    function GetProductName(id) {

        $.get('/OrderLine/GetProductNameById?ProductId=' + id, function (data) { 
                }).always(function(result) {
                    $("#ProductId").html(result);
                });
    
        }



    $("#ProductId").add(function () {

        var MyVal = $("#ProductId").html();
        console.log(MyVal);
        GetProductName(MyVal);

    });


</script>
```

Comment: <td id="ProductId"  <- this id should be unique

Comment: Just note that to some of us old schoolers that date back to ASP.net webforms, GridViews are something very specific and this is not it.

Answer (score 1):

1.The id of the html element should be unique , so you could add `class="ProductId"` to the each row of the `Products` column and change the jquery like below:

```
<td class="ProductId"  name="ProductId">@item.ProductId</td>

<script>
    function GetProductName(id,index) {
        $.get('/OrderLine/GetProductNameById?ProductId=' + id, function (data) {
        }).always(function (result) {
            $(index).html(result);
        });
    }
    $('.ProductId').each(function(i, obj) {
      var MyVal = $(this).html();
        console.log(MyVal);
        GetProductName(MyVal,this);
   });
</script>
```

2.A better method ,it seems that the [relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) between orderLine and Product is one-to-one , you could refer to the following model-design and use [`Include()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) to load the related product data to get the ProductName directly in the view :

*OrderLine*

```
public class OrderLine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

*Controller*

```
public IActionResult OrderList()
    {
        var model = _context.OrderLine.Include(o=>o.Product).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

*View*

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Products</th>
        <th>Detail</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr id="Mytr">
            <td>@item.Count</td>
            <td>@item.Price</td>
            <td class="ProductId" name="ProductId">@item.Product.Name</td>
            <td><a asp-controller="OderLine" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Detail</a></td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: If my workaround resolved your issue , could you mark the reply as answer? Refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235